# Python, raise multiple errors

Tags: python, exception

I receive a list with error messages. I want to raise a multiple custom errors at a time each with text from list:

```
class CustomError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


errors = [
    'error1', 'error2', 'error3'
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can raise `ExceptionGroup` in Python 3.11+:

```py
class CustomError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


errors = ["error1", "error2", "error3"]


raise ExceptionGroup("Error Message", [CustomError(e) for e in errors])
```

output:

```
  + Exception Group Traceback (most recent call last):
  |   File "", line 12, in <module>
  |     raise ExceptionGroup("Error Message", [CustomError(e) for e in errors])
  | ExceptionGroup: Error Message (3 sub-exceptions)
  +-+---------------- 1 ----------------
    | CustomError: error1
    +---------------- 2 ----------------
    | CustomError: error2
    +---------------- 3 ----------------
    | CustomError: error3
    +------------------------------------
```

you can also handle with either by `ExceptionGroup` or preferably new `except*` syntax.

Learn more about it here: https://peps.python.org/pep-0654/